# Shared PersistenceVolumeClaim(PVC) across namespaces

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-pvc

Is it possible to reference a PVC (in namespace-A) from namespace-B. Why I need that? I would like to allow the customer (private cloud) to point their volume through PVC, allowing them full control of the storage. At the Helm install time will ask for PVC information and will be used in the pod spec.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

It looks impossible, just because `PersistentVolumeClaim` is a namespaced object. You can look detailed answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35366775/9065705

Answer (score 18):

If you are using a ReadWriteMany-capable volume (like NFS/EFS), you can create multiple Persistent Volumes (PV) pointing to the same NFS volume, one for each namespace where you want to create a PVC. They can all use the same NFS volume at the same path, or specify different subPath to constrain them to certain directories.

Comment: Hi. Is there any online example available for this? I am using Azure FS with RWMany. How do we "point volumes in different namespace to one pvc" ?

Comment: This worked for me and it's the simplest solution with the fewest moving parts.  Just copy-paste your volume config into a new file with a different `name: ` attribute and reference *that* volume in your new pvc.

Answer (score 5):

Just in case someone arrives here from Google: It will now be possible with Kubernetes 1.26 (in Alpha): https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#cross-namespace-data-sources

Comment: As far as I understand it this doesn't allow to share the volume but only to allow the volume from another namespace as data source. So it creates a separate, independent volume which is just initialized to the data from the other namespace at the beginning.

Comment: Right - thank you for this clarification. I should have highlighted this in the original answer!

Answer (score -2):

#### **Our solution as follows：**

- First of all，It requires that the **persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy** of the source **PV** must be **Retain**.
- Secondly, We should add an **annotation** in the source **PVC** like that:

```yaml
pvc-shared-namespaces: NS1, NS2
```

- Thirdly, when we want to share  **PV** by the source **PVC**,  we can add two **annotation* in the second **PVC** like that:

```yaml
pvc-ref: pvc-1  # the name of the source PVC
pvc-ref-namespace: pvc-1-ns  # the namespace of the source PVC
```

#### **Volume create as follows：**

**CSI** takes out  **pvc-ref** and **pvc-ref-namespace** from **CreateVolumeRequest.Parameters** in **CreateVolume** interface:

1. Find out the source **PVC** based on **pvc-ref**  and **pvc-ref-namespace**, take out **pvc-shared-namespaces** from the source **PVC**, and judge whether the namespace of the new PVC is in it, if yes, go to 2, otherwise refuse to create;
2. Determine that the **reclaimPolicy** of the **StorageClass** of the new **PVC** is **Retain**, if yes, go to 3, otherwise refuse to create;
3. Find the source **PV** from the source **PVC**, and construct a **CreateVolumeResponse** based on the source **PV**.

> Note: The returned VolumeId is the **Spec.CSI.VolumeHandle** field of the source **PV**. After finding the source **PV**, you can determine whether the **persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy** of the source **PV** is **Retain**. If not, refuse to create.

Comment: Could you link to documentation? I find nothing on `pvc-shared-namespaces` over kubernetes official documentation, or even on google.

Comment: A nice idea, Jingyi, though the only place where this cool feature is mentioned is your comment here: https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/97908#issuecomment-895989478. Wish it really would be a working solution, though it doesn't seems to be that. ;-(